# Custom token wallet

Tags: wallets, erc-20

So custom coins/token sites always have their wallets on their site. The site generates the wallet for them. I saw the post about generating a wallet, and I have seen the ether wallet api and how to access it. But how do I get it to see my token and generate a wallet for the each user once they register?

Comment: Could you post links to the stuff you are referring to?

Comment: https://www.myetherapi.com/
This is the api I was looking at.